# How to wrap all views of a controller with a reusable template?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, dry

I have an ASP MVC 5 application that has a controller called `Member` in which all member related actions and views reside. All views that are created through this controller should be wrapped in a single piece of html that works as a menu. For instance a welcome view might look like:

```
<div class="member-menu">
    <!-- View code goes here -->
    <p>Welcome</p>
</div>
```

While another view might look like:

```
<div class="member-menu">
    <!-- View code goes here -->
    <p>Some other stuff here</p>
</div>
```

I would like to avoid repeating the menu code in every view if possible because it will likely grow larger in the future. I have done some research into shared views, child actions, and custom routing but can't seem to find anything that fits this pattern. Is what I am trying to do here easily possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific task, it looks like you need a Layout

MenuWrapperTemplate.cshtml

```
<div class="member-menu">
    @RenderBody();
</div>
```

Welcome view

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MenuWrapperTemplate.cshtml";
}
<!-- View code goes here -->
<p>Welcome</p>
```

If these are really menus, are you want them in the site's layout/master then take a look here [MVC where to render menu view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388518/mvc-where-to-render-menu-view)

You probably should get to grips with MVC, and the Html helpers (Render/RenderAction/partial) and how layouts work.

Hope that helps

Comment: This worked great once I added the original layout to the new layout (i.e. at the top of the menu layout I had to specify `Layout = "_Layout"`). Does this make sense? Thanks!